# Using M code get data from SQL has credential error

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery, m, credential-providers

I tried to connect data from SQL Server in my local using M code in Power Query. I can't see the difference between 2 codes, the first code connect and get data OK but the second code has error about credential. Pls tell me why it is

First code:

```
let
  Source = Sql.Database("MyServer", "AdventureWorksDW2014"),
  dbo_FactFinance = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="FactFinance"]}[Data]
in
  dbo_FactFinance
```

Second code:

```
    let
  Source = Sql.Databases("MyServer"),
  AdventureWorksDW2014 = Source{[Name = "[AdventureWorksDW2014]"]}[Data],
  dbo_FactFinance = 
  AdventureWorksDW2014{[Schema = "dbo", Item = "FactFinance"]}[Data],
in
  dbo_FactFinance
```

The error of the second code:
[image: the error of the second code:]

thank you guys so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your account has rights only for `AdventureWorksDW2014` database.

In the first code snippet, you are connecting directly to `AdventureWorksDW2014` database. In the second, you are connecting to the default database (usually this is `master`) and then the connection is switched to `AdventureWorksDW2014` database. So if the login on the SQL Server for your account has only `public` server role, and has user mapping to `AdventureWorksDW2014` (e.g. `db_owner`, `db_datareader`, etc.), then you must either use the first code, or to set the default database for your login to be `AdventureWorksDW2014`.

For more information take a look at [Create a Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Oh! I get it. Thanks so much!!